# Facing issue in uae currency code price to double in c#

Tags: c#

I have one function which parse the string text to double value and it works for almost all cultures except UAE

Can someone help in parsing UAE currency price to double

```csharp
public static double Parse(string text, string culture)
{
    return double.Parse(
        text.Replace(" ", ""),
        NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
        new CultureInfo(culture)
    );
}
```

Value for UAE which has issue: "د.إ. 259.00"

Culture code: "ar-AE"

Exception Getting:

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

[image: Visual Studio exception]

Comment: Added the exception

Comment: Is there any way you can create a [mcve]? And please, can you add those characters in the string using unicode escape sequences, so that we don't have to relying on copy-pasting characters that whatever code editor we use may or may not support?

Comment: For instance, I tried constructing a string by adding the currency symbol from that culture to a string with "259.00", with a space between the symbol and the number, and it parsed successfully, both with currency symbol before, and after, the number. Your string, however, copied from your question, compares equal to neither. Could it be that the string *looks* like it contains a space between the number and the symbol, but actually doesn't?

Comment: not sure, but I tried pasting same exact text, have also shared the image

Comment: I believe I have spotted a difference. The currency symbol in the culture has a [RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) character in there, if you remove that, the parsing fails. I guess the question then is if that should be counted as a required character in the currency symbol. The currency symbol in your string consists of the character `"\u062f\u002e\u0625\u002e"`, whereas the one in the culture is `"\u062f\u002e\u0625\u002e\u200f"`

Comment: `Parse("\u062f\u002e\u0625\u002e\u200f 259.00", "ar-AE")` succeeds, `Parse("\u062f\u002e\u0625\u002e 259.00", "ar-AE")` fails.

Comment: I would find the right place on github for the relevant part of the .net class libraries, and ask if this is intended behavior.

Comment: okay! - I was really confused, but you helped me in understanding the problem where it lies

Comment: I saw a different issue created about double.Parse that was transferred to [this github project - dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime), so I would assume this one should be there as well.

Comment: Is there anything we can do to parse the text which I'm getting - I want to parse it to double value

Comment: You will need to either strip off the currency symbol, or add in the missing RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain what happens, though I do not know if that is intended behavior or not. My guess would be that you should ask a question on the [dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) github project about this.

The issue is that the currency symbol in the currency contains a [RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) as its last character.

Example [LINQPad](https://linqpad.net) code:

```
new CultureInfo("ar-AE")
    .NumberFormat
    .CurrencySymbol
    .ToCharArray()
    .Select(c => new { c, i = ((int)c).ToString("x4") })
    .Dump();
```

outputs:

```
? 062f 
? 002e 
? 0625 
? 002e 
? 200f
```

*(I replaced the actual characters with question marks above because the RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK plays havoc with the editor here)*

Whereas the one in your string in your question is missing this mark, ie. the `200f` character at the end.

So this fails:

```
Parse("\u062f\u002e\u0625\u002e 259.00", "ar-AE")
```

but this succeeds:

```
Parse("\u062f\u002e\u0625\u002e\u200f 259.00", "ar-AE")
```

There are 23 such cultures in the .NET libraries:

```
ar 
ar-AE 
ar-BH 
ar-DZ 
ar-EG 
ar-IQ 
ar-JO 
ar-KW 
ar-LB 
ar-LY 
ar-MA 
ar-OM 
ar-QA 
ar-SA 
ar-SY 
ar-TN 
ar-YE 
ku 
ku-Arab 
ku-Arab-IQ 
lrc-IQ 
syr 
syr-SY
```

Comment: Did not work

`public static double Parse(string text, string culture)
        {
            if (culture.Contains("AE"))
            {
                var righttoleft = ((Char)0x200F);
                text = text + (righttoleft).ToString();
                
            }
            if (text.ToLower().Equals("free"))
                return 0;
            else   
                return double.Parse(text.Replace(" ", ""), NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                   new CultureInfo(culture));
        }`

Comment: You have to add the mark at the right place, the currency symbol characters are at the start of the string, even though they are displayed to the right of the number. The first 4 characters in your string is the currency code, you have to insert that mark as the 5th character.